# Running NUnit tests on different configuration

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm new to .Net and hence don't know if the approach which I'm following below is correct or is there any better way to do it. Can someone please suggest ?

I want to keep different set of configuration for different environments (DEV,QA, UAT, etc) and  based on user input load that environment config and start my Nunit tests.

I'm planning to create a different resource file for each of these for ex - QA.resx, DEV.resx, etc and then just load specific resource file based on user input.

for ex.

```
QA.resx will have
hostname=sample.qa.com
port=1234

DEV.resx will have
hostname=sample.dev.com
port=4321
```

And then at runtime if I specify something like env=DEV then it should load configuration from DEV.resx and start running the test cases.

Is this a good approach ?

Comment: Define "user input"? What do those resource files contain?

Comment: @MarioDS -  User input will be the environment on which he wants the tests to run for ex. QA, DEV, UAT, etc and the resource file will contain the connection settings related to that environment. Also updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good approach ?

I don't think so.

First of all, your Unit Test should not depend on environment you're using. True Unit Test should not have any external dependency, like database, file system, external services, etc. Thus UT execution should be the same no matter whether it's launched on a developer workstation or CI server.

If your application requires different configurations for different environments (it's a very common case), the best choice is to use config transformations. Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) for details.

Comment: This is assuming that Nunit is being used for traditional unit testing. You are correct in saying that Unit Tests should be independent and not have any concept of configuration, however NUnit can also used for functional UI (Selenium) or API testing. In this scenarios, it is perfectly valid to require the ability to configure per environment